# error ant design al deshabilitar componente ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formularios

estoy realizando un cuestionario en la que hay dos Radiobutton uno que dice si y otro dice no, necesito que al apretar si me abilite un datePiker y al apretar no que lo desabilite, asi:

ahorita se puede apretando solo el si el si lo abilita y lo desabilita y quiero queel si habilite y el no desabilite mi codigo es este:

```
toggleDisable = (disabled) => this.setState({ disabled })
  toggleDisable = () => {
    this.setState({ disabled: !this.state.disabled });
  };

                     <div className="dateP mb-4">
                        <Row>
                          <Radio value={1}
                            onClick={this.toggleDisable}>SI</Radio>
                          <Radio value={2} value="nothingtwo"
                            style={{ lineHeight: "32px" }}>NO</Radio>
                        </Row>
                      </div>

                       <DatePicker onChange={onChange}
                        disabled={this.state.disabled} />
```

repito lo que quiero hacer es que en el **SI** el datepiker se active y en el **NO** se desactive, si alguien me puede ayudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor sería colocarlo en un Radio.Group y la función toggleDisable la asignas al onChange del Radio.Group.

Ejemplo:

```
 toggleDisable = (e) => this.setState({ disabled: e.target.value === 2})
```

Y en tus opciones sería

```
  <Radio.Group onChange={this.toggleDisable}>
    <Radio value={1}>SI</Radio>
    <Radio value={2}>NO</Radio>
  </Radio.Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues podrias desabiltar usando el state para que no se muestre el calendario.

Algo asi

```
const [showCalendar, setShowCalendar] = useState(false)
```

y asi solo cambiar el setShowCalendar(true) cuando necesites.